# How to connect to an SSID from an app built with Expo and React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

I want my app to be able to connect to a Wifi network whose SSID and password are already gonna be hardcoded in the app. Hope there is a way to do this in expo. I know I could use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-reborn but probably do not want to eject out of expo.

Comment: Yes, you need to eject your project  and then follow the guide wrote on package to link library in iOs/Android project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question here for anyone who's facing the same problem.
With the latest Expo updates now we can add react-native packages to the managed expo workflow without ever ejecting. What that means is we can install https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wifi-reborn to our Expo project.

We'll just be needing to install `expo-dev-client` to our project and then use EAS build. Consider reading this guide to follow the exact steps needed https://docs.expo.dev/development/getting-started/

Here is a little blog post I wrote discussing about the same.
https://blog.chiragsrvstv.dev/install-native-modules-with-expo